# Run gulp from child directories?

Tags: gulp

I currently have a file structure like this

```
SASS
    gulpfile.js
    node_modules
    sites
        example-site
            scss
            css
        example-site-two
            scss
            css
        example-site-three
            scss
            css
```

I have gulp installed in the main parent SASS folder with a task 'sass-all' that can go through every single sites scss folder and compile it into css.

I'm trying to write a new task called 'sass-single' which can be run from any of the example-site folders. So let's say I'm in the folder "example-site-two", I want to be able to cmd and do 'gulp sass-single' and ONLY have it compile the SASS in this site. Same thing for a watch-single task I'd like to setup.

Problem is whenever I run this task from a site folder, it changes my working directory up to the parent SASS folder. I don't want to have 100 different tasks for every different site, I'd prefer to just have one 'sass-single' task thats smart enough to only compile the files from the folder I was in when I ran the script.

**current Gulp task attempt**

```
    gulp.task('sass-single', function () {
      process.chdir('./');

      // Where are the SCSS files?
      var input = './scss/*.scss';

      // Where do you want to save the compiles CSS file?
      var output = './css';

      return gulp
        .src(input)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
    });
```

However this goes back to the main SASS folder and then just does nothing.
 How would I go about modifying this to be able to run from any site folder and have it only do it for that site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change the current working directory (CWD) back to the directory where you invoked `gulp` then this won't work:

```
process.chdir('./');
```

That's a relative path. Relative paths are relative to the CWD. But by the time you execute `process.chdir('./')` Gulp has already changed the CWD to the directory where your Gulpfile.js is located. So you're just changing the CWD to ... the CWD.

You could explicitly pass a CWD to `gulp` on the command line:

```
SASS/sites/example-site> gulp --cwd .
```

But that would get annoying pretty quickly.

Luckily for you [Gulp stores the original CWD](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/a54996c/bin/gulp.js#L19) in `process.env.INIT_CWD` before changing it. So you can use the following in your task to change the CWD back to the original:

```
process.chdir(process.env.INIT_CWD);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that's two days in a row you helped me out, very much appreciated! Still getting the hang of gulp, lol.

Comment: That `process.env.INIT_CWD` needs to be highlighted in red and font-size 100px. Thanks!