# get the path where npm gulp called from

Tags: node.js, gulp

New with gulp and npm, I am trying to write a script that takes into account the current directory:

```
gulp.task('render', function(){
    var folder = process.cwd();
    console.info("I am called from:" + folder);
    //renderThisData(folder + "/data.json");
})
```

I tried this one as well, it gives same result:

```
gulp.task('render', function(){
    var folder = process.env.INIT_CWD;
    console.info("I am called from:" + folder);
    //renderThisData(folder + "/data.json");
})
```

where my tree is like:

```
root
|--- package.json
|--- gulpfile.js
|--- folder1
|    |--- data.json
|--- folder2
|    |--- data.json
|--- folder3
|    |--- data.json
```

When I run the script from inside one particular folder, the above script gives always the path where the gulpfile is :-(

```
D:\root\folder1>npm run render
I am called from D:\root
```

One work around i found is to use params:

```
 npm run render -- --folder=folder1
```

and then read/use the param value in my code.
I am wondering if there are other ways to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run gulp from child directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891227/run-gulp-from-child-directories)

Comment: The `process.env.INIT_CWD` solution only works if you run `gulp render` instead of `npm run render`. In the latter case it's `npm` that changes the CWD, so `gulp` never get's to see the original CWD.

Comment: indeed, it does not work in my case (using npm).

Answer (score 0):

`npm run` will always run from your root directory (if it's not changed in your script).

You can use `process.env.INIT_CWD` which is the original cwd it was launched from (Added in version 3.8.1) if you can run `gulp 'task'` instead of using `npm` or pass the folder name by parameter `npm run render -- --folder=${PWD##*/}`