# How do I list all folder names that have files changed in Git?

Tags: bash, git, shell

`git diff --name-only` or `git diff --name-status` will list all files that have been changed, however there is no command to list all folder names that contain files changed.

For example, with this directory tree:

```
test/
|
|__B/
|
|____b1.txt
|
|__C/
|
|____c1.txt
```

If `b1.txt` and `c1.txt` have changed, I'd like to get `B` and `C` as the output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a way:

```sh
git diff --name-only | xargs -L1 dirname | uniq
```

---

**Explanation**

- `git diff --name-only`: list all changed files
- `xargs -L1 dirname`: remove filenames to keep only directories
- `uniq`: remove duplicates

You can create [an alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) so you don't have to type the whole command each time you need it:

```sh
alias git-diff-folders="git diff --name-only | xargs -L1 dirname | uniq"
```

Comment: dirs, not folders

Comment: You could add sort so that the dirs are not duplicated `git diff --name-only | xargs -L1 dirname | sort | uniq`.

Answer (score 2):

This command would give results of top level directories. 
`git status | cut -d'/' -f1`

For a more in depth solution I am currently working with 
${PWD##*/} in bash to find a more correct solution to your problem.

Trying to write a solution for you in git that is simular to this npm solution:

[get the path where npm gulp called from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366507/get-the-path-where-npm-gulp-called-from)

im no longer searching for the answer on this one,

`git diff --name-only | xargs -L1 dirname | uniq`

was the correct answer provided by Pᴇʜ

it works on my mac computer after his edit's